# SwiftUI isEditing Mode .inactive, .active

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, editmode

Have edit button for edit mode just with icon and when pressing button then changes and icon, but if I move rove or delete, then edit mode turns off but button stays the same in the isEditing active, and if need again use isEditing then need to press two times and not one like suppose to be.
For earlier versions for iOS than 16.0

```
@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    private var isEditing: Bool {
        editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false
    }
 var body: some View {
 NavigationView {
   List {
   Section(header: Text("Example View.")) {
                ForEach(examples) { example in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ExampleView(example: example)) {
                        RowView(example: example)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteRow)
                .onMove(perform: moveRow)
            }
       .toolbar {
       ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    if #unavailable(iOS 16.0) {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                editMode?.wrappedValue = isEditing ? .inactive : .active
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: isEditing ? "list.bullet.rectangle.fill" : "list.bullet.rectangle")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        })
                    } else {
//                        For iOS 16 without editing button
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried change line in:

```
Image(systemName: isEditing ? "list.bullet.rectangle.fill" : "list.bullet.rectangle", !isEditing, "list.bullet.rectangle")
```

but then get error on .toolbar view, *"Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Visibility' that does not accept a closure"* so how to do if wanna after isEditing action icon changes together?

Comment: Are you aware of [`EditButton`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editbutton)?

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show the full error messages you get and on which line of the code.

Comment: @Sweeper, I think when I did that button was EditButton without onMove? Now not sure but something was missing in or needed icon functionality like this in example, but also not working properly like needed.

Comment: @workingdog-support-ukraine Edited description what try and what error get.

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What you are showing us is far from a minimal reproducible example code. All the contextual code has a major effect on your `ToolbarItemGroup` that you show.